# SQL JOIN two tables & second table only gets latest entry & with 2 ids

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables.

MARKET TABLE

```
ID       main_key     sub_key     name      created_at
------------------------------------------------------
1        1            1           bottle    1606636000
2        2            1           flask     1606642546
3        2            2           flask     1606650045
4        3            1           can       1606650445
5        3            2           can       1606651546
6        4            1           glass     1606652545
```

MARKET_UPDATES TABLE

```
ID       main_key     sub_key     price     update
------------------------------------------------------
1        1            1           100       1606665555
2        2            1           120       1606665555
3        2            2           150       1606665555
4        3            1           500       1606665555
5        3            2           550       1606665555
6        4            1           25        1606665555

7        1            1           110       1606665666
8        2            1           135       1606665666
9        2            2           145       1606665666
10       3            1           490       1606665666
11       3            2           440       1606665666
12       4            1           29        1606665666
```

I've tried this.

```
SELECT *
FROM market m
JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(id) max_id, fk_main_key
   FROM market_update
   GROUP BY fk_main_key, sub_key
) m_max ON (m_max.fk_main_key = m.main_key)
JOIN market_update mu ON (mu.id = m_max.max_id)
```

But it multiples it a lot of times and I end up with a lot of the same lines. I think it multiples `main_key` amount and `sub_key` amount.

I am trying to `JOIN` MARKET_UPDATES into MARKET so I can get the latest prices from MARKET_UPDATES, but my issue is that I have 2 id's that I have to check on, `main_key` & `sub_key`.

So I have to merge the MARKET table with id(7-12) in MARKET_UPDATES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way based on your query :

```
SELECT *
FROM market m
JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(id) max_id , fk_main_key, sub_key
   FROM market_update
   GROUP BY fk_main_key, sub_key
) m_max 
ON (m_max.fk_main_key = m.main_key 
    and m_max.sub_key = m.sub_key)
JOIN market_update mu ON (mu.id = m_max.max_id)
```

and here is another way using window function `RANK()` :

```
SELECT *
FROM market m
JOIN (
   SELECT id
        , fk_main_key
        , sub_key 
        , rank() over (partition by fk_main_key, sub_key order by id desc ) rnk
   FROM market_updat  
) mu 
ON mu.fk_main_key = m.main_key 
and mu.sub_key = m.sub_key
and  rnk = 1
```

Comment: Damn, the first on worked. No idea why I haven't thought of the AND. Gonna try the second on as soon as a have a little more time and maybe compare the speed of both. 

THANK YOU! You saved my day!

Comment: second one will perform much better